# Upsampling2D output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I don't really understand the Keras `UpSampling2D` output shape, for example the following code should output a tensor of `shape=(1,1,6,6)` however it outputs a tensor of `shape=(1, 2, 6, 3)` the output channels look correct in terms of the data but I am confused about the shape:

```
input_shape = (1, 1, 3, 3) 
x = np.arange(np.prod(input_shape)).reshape(input_shape) 
y = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
```

**Tensor:**

```
  [[[[0 1 2]
    [3 4 5]
   [6 7 8]]]]
```

**Output:**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[0 1 2]
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
[6 7 8]]

[[0 1 2]
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
[6 7 8]]]], shape=(1, 2, 6, 3), dtype=int64)
```

**Expected output:**

```
 tf.Tensor([[0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 4., 4., 5., 5.],
       [3., 3., 4., 4., 5., 5.],
       [6., 6., 7., 7., 8., 8.],
       [6., 6., 7., 7., 8., 8.]], dtype=float32)
```

I understand how to use `tf.concat` to get the desired output, I am trying to understand the behavior of the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about the position of the channel index.

UpSampling2D expects the input to be like `(nb_samples, height, width, channels)`, and not `(nb_samples, channels, height, width)`.

You would get the output you expect with the following code:

```
input_shape = (1, 3, 3, 1) 
x = np.arange(np.prod(input_shape)).reshape(input_shape) 
y = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(x)
```

In this case, the shape of `y` is `(1, 6, 6, 1)`, and `y[0, :, :, 0]` is equal to:

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2],
   [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
   [3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
   [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8],
   [6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8]])>
```

Edit: as @xdurch0 points out, it is about using `channels_first` or `channels_last` data format, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/image_data_format).

Comment: It should be noted that this is about using `channels_first` vs `channels_last` data format, where the latter is the default but OP seems to be assuming the former.